# Redirect www.xxx.com URL to xxx.com on Heroku

Tags: domain-name-system, url

I'm using pointDNS

I have an alias: `xxx.com` to the `xxx.herokudns.com`.
Now I have added a CNAME `www.xxx.com` and redirected it to `xxx.herokudns.com` (also tried `xxx.com` with the same result).

What I want is that the `www` disappears in the URL bar in the browser and I only see `xxx.com`

```
nslookup xxx.com
OK

nslookup www.xxx.com
Non-authoritative answer:
www.xxx.com canonical name = xxx.com.
..
```

The above seems really fine to me, but why is the www still in my browser? Or do I have to handle this somewhere else? I configured it as described here: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirect-heroku/

Comment: The site you linked says: "3. In your application, intercept the incoming request. If the request host is not the canonical one, redirect the request to the canonical domain. How to perform a redirect depends on the programming language and/or framework your application is developed with." It appears you haven't done this yet.

Answer (score 1):

this is not related to your DNS settings directly, you have to implement redirect in your app.

another way, if it is not possible to fix the app - you can use cloudflare and setup forwarding rule there, using page rules.